# Hive wont run in Hortonworks 2.2.4

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I've just downloaded Hortonworks Sandbox 2.2.4, and I noticed when I follow the [Hortonwork's tutorial on Hive](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-hive/), I get this,

```
HCatClienterroroncreatetable: {
    "statement": "use default; create table nyse_stocks(`exchange` string, `stock_symbol` string, `date` string, `stock_price_open` float, `stock_price_high` float, `stock_price_low` float, `stock_price_close` float, `stock_volume` bigint, `stock_price_adj_close` float) row format delimited fields terminated by '\\t';",
    "error": "unable to create table: nyse_stocks",
    "exec": {
        "stdout": "",
        "stderr": "
        15/05/05 09:57:50 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.heapsize does not exist
        15/05/05 09:57:50 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
        SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
        SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: Found binding in                                                         [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.4.2-2-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
        SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
        SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
        Command  was terminated due to timeout(60000ms).  See templeton.exec.timeout property",
        "exitcode": 143
    }
}(error500)
```

When I ssh into the Sandbox, and I simply type `hive` on shell, I get this the output inside the stderr,

```
15/05/05 09:57:50 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.heapsize does not exist
15/05/05 09:57:50 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.server2.enable.impersonation does not exist
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in                                                         [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.2.2.4.2-2-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem (due to incompatibility) with SerDe jar, inside sandbox.
I had the same problem and after a few googles, I found a solution at 
https://github.com/brandonswilson.

Here is what I did:

a-)removed the first line from hiveddl.sql

b-)changed line 34 to:
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'

That's it!

(After to run hive -f hiveddl.sql I got a problem at line 119:

-- FAILED: SemanticException Unrecognized file format in STORED AS clause: 'RCFILESE' --

Was: STORED AS RCFilese

I changed to: STORED AS RCFile

You could try to change before to run.)

Daniel Galizi.